# How to pass multiple file to be ran in Playwright?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, playwright

According to the [Playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/running-tests#run-specific-tests), many test directories should be passed in format `tests/todo-page/ tests/landing-page/` (spaces as separators) so by logic I used the same format for test files `path/to/test1.ts path/to/test2.ts` (spaces as separators), but when I do this only the first one (`path/to/test1.ts`) is taken into account.

So final version looks like this

`yarn playwright test path/to/test1.ts path/to/test2.ts --shard 1/2`

I also tried out of curiosity removing shards (but I need it, so it's "no go") and when I remove it, it takes the last test (`path/to/test2.ts`).

How to do it? I need to pass it through CLI as our CI calculates what has to be ran (pretty "random", depends on few things), so solutions as "create new project" or "tag them" wouldn't do.